# Creating a table for use in Excel

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for some assistance with a PHP script I'm writing. It creates a table that is then exported to an Excel file for download.

The issues as I see them are as follows:

`$students` contains 559 items and the `$classes` has 22 items and `$attributes` has 6 items:

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($students as $student){
    $pupil = Students::retrieveByPK($student['adno']); ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo strtoupper($pupil->surname); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $pupil->first_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $pupil->year_group; ?></td>
    <?php foreach($classes as $class){
        $shortYear = str_replace('Year ', '',$pupil->year_group);
        $slashPos = strpos($class['class_name'],'/');
        $className = $shortYear.substr($class['class_name'],1);
        $classId = Classes::idFromClassName($className); 
        foreach($attributes as $attribute){
           $attr = AttributeResults::getExportAttribute($pupil->adno, $classId, $attribute['attribute_id']); ?>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $attr[0]['attribute_value']; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
     <?php } ?>
</tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

I'm essentially running the `AttributeResults::getExportAttribute` method in the region of 74000 times. Is there a better way of bringing this data back?

Comment: Depends, where is all that data coming from? Is each of your static class calls a database query?

Comment: Yes at the moment they are

Comment: Then you should use one big SQL query to get the data instead of 74000 tiny ones.

Comment: I think I still need to run for each of the $classes as the next level of info ($attributes) comes specifically from the id's I get in the $classes, so essentially you would suggest running 22 larger queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what your better off doing is to have a join on your database call, so that the class data and student data is returned in one object.